# Entity Framework Core partial classes

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I am trying to reuse my model and context in multiple projects. To do so I created a project/Nuget package (.Net Standard 2.0) containing the model classes, as well as the context. This works well in .Net Core as well as in Windows Forms. The following is a simplified sample of what I did:

Entity Framework project (EF Core 2.0):

`Person.cs`:

```
namespace EfCoreLib {
    public class Person {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(40)]
        public string Firstname { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(40)]
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`PersonContext.cs`:

```
namespace EfCoreLib {
    public class PersonContext:DbContext {
        public DbSet<Person> Persons{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

Windows Forms application project:

`PersonForm.cs`

```
public partial class PersonForm : Form {
        public PersonForm() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void PersonForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            PersonContext db = new PersonContext();
            var allPersons = from p in db.Persons select p;
        }
 }
```

In the Windows Forms application I would like to have some model properties for  binding purposes only (e.g. bool to bind on enabled property of a control or formatted string to display in a grid). In EF6 I used partial classes in the same namespace as my model (which also had to be a partial class) to implement this. This used to work with EF 6:

`Person.cs` in Windows Forms application project:

```
namespace EfCoreLib {
    public partial class Person {
        public string Displayname {
            get {
                return $"{Firstname} {Lastname}";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I try this with EF Core, I will receive an error CS103 in Person.cs as it does recognize the properties firstname and lastname. Furthermore there will be an error CS0436 in `PersonForm.cs`.

As a workaround I could implement the properties in the EF Project, but as they are unique to the consuming application this means I would need to redeploy the package each time i need a change for one of the apps.

Does anybody know how to use the model and context from the EF project and extend it with some properties in the consuming app?

Comment: Partial definitions cannot span multiple modules. I would use T4 to read the entities and create ViewModels as partial classes for each of them. Then I would simply add the needed logic. Flexible, fast and remove error due to copy and paste. And i would go for WPF... no Forms

Comment: An additional side-effect is that you can read the attributes and do some validation logic using them. For example using INotifyDataErrorInfo

Comment: A "bool to bind on enabled property" belongs on a ViewModel. Which is what you need here - don't stretch your Model to do GUI stuff. Look into MVP for WinForms or WPF+MVVM .

Comment: @Marco The first part of your comment is fine. But the second is off topic. *"And i would go for WPF..."* - what if that's not your choice and you can't. It has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 0):

In the end @Marco posted the answer in his comment.

> Partial definitions cannot span multiple modules.

Thanks to all for the input regarding ways on how to implement a solution. I am aware of the option of creating a view model, actually I already do this in a lot of cases, sometimes it would just be nice to spare the effort of creating an additional class which is mostly copy & paste.